# Replace If with Loop

Tags: c#

i am new to c# and this question may sound dumb...
I am programing a bot that plays music when i send a command, i want to create some kind of loop to replace the "if" but i dont know how or what type of loop...

This is my void Function that reads a content from a specific .txt file and plays the songs in sequence: https://pastebin.com/sPG1VtnN

For testing purposes i made a .txt file called "MTJ Dream" with this on the first line:

```
songlist "Break The Walls" "Fools Gold" "Out Of My League" "The Walker"
```

The name of the .txt file is equal to a folder on a specific path, and the program reads everything that is inside the double quotes, plays the song in sequence, and shows me the list with all strings on this code.
this is the list of strings of this part of my code that may need to be replaced:

```
pONE: Content/config/teste/
pTWO: Content/config/teste/MTJ Dream.txt
line: songlist "Break The Walls" "Fools Gold" "Out Of My League" "The Walker"
binder1: "Break The Walls" "Fools Gold" "Out Of My League" "The Walker"
output1: Break The Walls
binder2: "Fools Gold" "Out Of My League" "The Walker"
output2: Fools Gold
binder3: "Out Of My League" "The Walker"
output3: Out Of My League
binder4: "The Walker"
output4: The Walker
```

I was thinking about writing a foreach loop, but as i sayd... i am new to c# and i dont know how to do a foreach in this situation...

If this question is Duplicated, please consider sending me the question that you think may solve my problem!

Comment: What you probably need is a Dictionary<string, string> and not a loop. You are using a string to lookup another string.

Comment: I will do a research about "Dictionary<string, string>" now and i will see if i can re-write the code with the same results and less if statements, Thanks ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the pattern you'll want to follow. Please note that I did not test this code and might have gotten something wrong. It's just to demonstrate roughly how to do what I think you're asking.

```
public static void Songlist(string fn)
{
    filename = fn;
    foldername = filename + '/';
    pTWO = pONE + filename + ".txt";

    using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(pTWO))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();

            if (line.StartsWith("songlist "))
            {
                var outputs = new List<string>();

                // compile all the outputs
                var position = 9;
                while (position <= line.Length)
                {
                    string lister = line.Remove(0, position);
                    string output = lister.Split('"', '"')[1];
                    outputs.Add(output);
                    position += (2 + output.Length + 1);
                }

                // iterate over all the outputs
                foreach (var output in outputs)
                {
                    if (Directory.Exists("Content/musics/" + foldername) && output != null && File.Exists("Content/musics/" + foldername + output + ".mp3"))
                    {
                        media.controls.stop();
                        media.URL = "Content/musics/" + foldername + output + ".mp3";
                        media.controls.play();

                        Console.WriteLine("media.controls.currentPosition :: " + media.controls.currentPosition);
                        Console.WriteLine("media.currentMedia.duration    :: " + media.currentMedia.duration);

                        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, your code is really what i was looking for, Thanks! ^^